# Why does this javascript code disable secure connection (SSL certificate I think) from my Blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I did the test and every time I put this code in my template, the padlock (secure connection) stays like [this](https://gyazo.com/29b248cef781b169c9e1affc27fdbb9d) and when you take it it stays like [this](https://gyazo.com/b8bdfebf97782f5125266b80e59b68c1).
This code is essential for my blogger, so if I could make a correction in the code or something like that to fix this error, thank you.

My blog link:[TRITEK](https://trit3k.blogspot.com/)

```js
//<![CDATA[
function labelthumbs(t) {
    for (var e = 0; e < numposts; e++) {
        var n, r = t.feed.entry[e],
            m = r.title.$t;
        if (e == t.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var i = 0; i < r.link.length; i++) {
            if ("replies" == r.link[i].rel && "text/html" == r.link[i].type) var l = r.link[i].title,
                o = r.link[i].href;
            if ("alternate" == r.link[i].rel) {
                n = r.link[i].href;
                break
            }
        }
        var u;
        try {
            u = r.media$thumbnail.url, u = u.replace("/s72-c/", "/w" + thumb_width + "-h" + thumb_height + "-c/")
        } catch (h) {
            s = r.content.$t, a = s.indexOf("<img"), b = s.indexOf('src="', a), c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5), d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5), u = -1 != a && -1 != b && -1 != c && "" != d ? d : no_thumb
        }
        var p = r.published.$t,
            w = p.substring(0, 4),
            _ = p.substring(5, 7),
            f = p.substring(8, 10),
            g = new Array;
        g[1] = "January", g[2] = "February", g[3] = "March", g[4] = "April", g[5] = "May", g[6] = "June", g[7] = "July", g[8] = "August", g[9] = "September", g[10] = "October", g[11] = "November", g[12] = "December", document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_left">'), document.write('<ul class="newsmartpik_thumbs">'), document.write("<li>"), 1 == showpostthumbnails && document.write('<div class="block-image2"><div class="thumb2"><a href="' + n + '"><span class="rollover"></span><img width="' + thumb_width + '" height="' + thumb_height + '" alt="' + m + '" src="' + u + '"/></a></div></div>'), document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_title"><a href="' + n + '" target ="_top">' + m + "</a></span>");
        var v = "";
        if (document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_meta">'), 1 == showpostdate && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_date">' + g[parseInt(_)] + " " + f + ", " + w + "</span>"), 1 == showcommentnum && ("1 Comments" == l && (l = "1 Comments"), "0 Comments" == l && (l = "0 Comments"), showcomment = '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_comment"><a href="' + o + '">' + l + "</a></span>", v += showcomment), 1 == displaymore && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_more"><a href="' + n + '" class="url" target ="_top">Read More...</a></span>'), document.write(v), document.write("</span>"), document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_summary">'), "content" in r) var y = r.content.$t;
        else if ("summary" in r) var y = r.summary.$t;
        else var y = "";
        var k = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
        if (y = y.replace(k, ""), 1 == showpostsummary)
            if (y.length < numchars) document.write(""), document.write(y), document.write("");
            else {
                document.write(""), y = y.substring(0, numchars);
                var $ = y.lastIndexOf(" ");
                y = y.substring(0, $), document.write(y + "..."), document.write("")
            }
        document.write("</span>"), document.write("</li>"), document.write("</ul>"), document.write("</span>")
    }
    document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_right">'), document.write('<ul class="newsmartpik_thumbs2">');
    for (var e = 1; e < numposts2; e++) {
        var n, r = t.feed.entry[e],
            m = r.title.$t;
        if (e == t.feed.entry.length) break;
        for (var i = 1; i < r.link.length; i++) {
            if ("replies" == r.link[i].rel && "text/html" == r.link[i].type) var l = r.link[i].title,
                o = r.link[i].href;
            if ("alternate" == r.link[i].rel) {
                n = r.link[i].href;
                break
            }
        }
        var x;
        try {newsmartpik_left
            x = r.media$thumbnail.url.replace("/s72-c/", "/w" + thumb_width2 + "-h" + thumb_height2 + "-c/")
        } catch (h) {
            s = r.content.$t, a = s.indexOf("<img"), b = s.indexOf('src="', a), c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5), d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5), x = -1 != a && -1 != b && -1 != c && "" != d ? d : no_thumb2
        }
        var p = r.published.$t,
            w = p.substring(0, 4),
            _ = p.substring(5, 7),
            f = p.substring(8, 10);
        1 == showpostthumbnails2 && document.write('<a href="' + n + '"><div class="cat_thumb2"><img width="' + thumb_width2 + '" height="' + thumb_height2 + '" alt="' + m + '" src="' + x + '"/></div></a>'), document.write("<li>"), document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_title newsmartpik_title2"><a href="' + n + '" target ="_top">' + m + "</a></span>");
        var v = "";
        document.write('<span class="newsmartpik_meta newsmartpik_meta2">'), 1 == showpostdate2 && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_date">' + g[parseInt(_)] + " " + f + ", " + w + "</span>"), 1 == showcommentnum2 && ("1 Comment" == l && (l = "1 Comments"), "0 Comment" == l && (l = "0 Comments"), showcomment = '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_comment newsmartpik_meta_comment2"><a href="' + o + '">' + l + "</a></span>", v += showcomment), 1 == displaymore2 && (v = v + '<span class="newsmartpik_meta_more newsmartpik_meta_more2"><a href="' + n + '" class="url" target ="_top">Ler Mais</a></span>'), document.write(v), document.write("</span>"), document.write("</li>")
    }
    document.write("</ul>"), document.write("</span>")
}
//]]>
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable, but my guess is it adds some image or something with http instead of https

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is here**:
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://trit3k.blogspot.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, **but requested an insecure image** 'http://aldeia.biz/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Snapchat-flashy-features.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Try to upload your own files xD